# PHP Curl POST Request to iFrame

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe, php-curl

I need to track a tracking number in this tracking website. However, the form is in iFrame div, how do I POST request using CURL in PHP? Below is my code.

iFrame src:

```
https://home.abxexpress.com.my/track_multiple.html
```

Original src:

```
https://abxexpress.com.my/Home/Tracking
```

Controller:

```
public function track($trackingID)
    {
      $data = array(
        'tairbillno'  => $trackingID
    );

    print_r($data);

    $url = file_get_contents('https://home.abxexpress.com.my/track_multiple.html');

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    echo $result;
}
```

Sample of tracking number:

```
99951513362
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this php-curl Code to send a simple post request to callback-page to get tracking info in html format,
after you can print content direct in your website(its work correctly,with the original style   ), also you can use this content to extract all info you want , by any DOM extract librery like :  [php DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://home.abxexpress.com.my/track_multipleResult.asp?vsearch=True');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "tairbillno=99951513362");//replace number your traking number 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Origin: https://home.abxexpress.com.my';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document';
$headers[] = 'Referer: https://home.abxexpress.com.my/track_multiple.html';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: it,it-IT;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6';
$headers[] = 'Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDAWDDSADQ=LLOJGMICLOOKHGEHJHPBMBKE';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```